# rspec include matcher fails with equal arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, rspec, matcher

I'm testing the `active` scope of `SystemCommission`, I have the following test:

```
  expected = [active, no_starting, no_ending]
  expect(SystemCommission.active.map(&:id)).to include expected.map(&:id)
```

it fails with:

```
Failure/Error: expect(SystemCommission.active.map(&:id)).to include expected.map(&:id)
       expected [1, 2, 3] to include [1, 2, 3]
```

I had to use the `id`s because it wasn't matching the objects.

any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `[1, 2, 3]` does not include `[1, 2, 3]`

To make that pass it would look something like: `[1, 2, 3, [1, 2, 3]]`

splat your array:

`expect(SystemCommission.active.map(&:id)).to include *expected.map(&:id)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured that `include` parameters is not an array, but a list of items,

so changing the test to:

```
  expect(SystemCommission.active.map(&:id)).to include *expected.map(&:id)
```

did the trick